# Installed node js getting "The syntax of the command is incoorect"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I updated node.js yesterday on my computer and it appears to have installed fine. If I type -v I get the correct information.

```
node -v
```

I get the correct version number of v16.13.1

However when I try to type

```
npm -v
```

I get the three lines of

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect. 
The syntax of the command is incorrect. 
The syntax of the command is incorrect. 
/F was unexpected at this time.
```

System Info

Windows 10 Home 64-bit, OS build 19043.1348

Answer (score 0):

You need to Add `C:\Program Files\nodejs` to your PATH environment variable.

1- Search in start menu for **"Edit system environment variables"**

2- Click "**Environment Variables"**

3- In the "System Variables" find path and click to edit

4- add nodejs path

5- add npm path %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm

6- close all command prompts and open it again.